# Insert multiple rows in database using codeigniter

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter, controller

I want to insert multiple rows in the database with the use of codeigniter but i don't have any idea on how to properly implement it for my program to work. What I want is to fetch the data from the accounts table and use one of its attribute as a validation parameter in my if else statement. If the condition is met, it will populate the table with the announcement table contents along with the user id of all the accounts which met the proper conditions. Can you please help me to figure this thing out? Thank you.

Here's the snippet of my code.

## CONTROLLER

```
public function announceSubmit(){
        $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
        $uType = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
        $title = $this->input->post('title', true);
        $users = $this->input->post('users', true);
        $content = $this->input->post('descr', true);

        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/announcements/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = '25000';

        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

            if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image-source')){
                print_r($this->upload->display_errors());
            }else{

                $newData = $this->Bid_Model->fetchItems('accounts');


                if($users == $uType){

                    foreach($newData as $user):
                        $userIDs = $user->user_id;
                    endforeach;

                        $announce_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');

                        $data = array(
                            'title' => $title,
                            'user_type' => $users,
                            'content' => $content,
                            'image' => $announce_image,
                            'admin_user_id' => $id,
                            'user_id' => $userIDs
                        ); 

                        $this->Bid_Model->insertItem('announcements', $data);
                }


                redirect('dashboard');
            }
        }
```

## CREATE ANNOUNCEMENT VIEW

```
<style>
  #image-preview {
    display: none;
    width: 250px;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #cke_descr {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
</style>
<div class="right_col" role="main">
  <div class="">
    <div class="page-title">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="x_panel">
            <div class="x_title">
              <h2>Create Announcement</h2>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="x_content">
              <br />
              <form id="demo-form2" data-parsley-validate class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?=base_url()?>admin/announceSubmit">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="title">Title<span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="users">Users <span class="required">*</span>
                  </label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <select type="text" id="users" name="users" required="required" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12">
                      <option value="6">Vendor Team Manager</option>
                      <option value="2">Project Manager</option>
                      <option value="7">Vendor Project Manager</option>
                      <option value="3">Vice President</option>
                      <option value="5">Accountant</option>
                      <option value="8">Project Developers</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">

                  <div class="class"></div>

                  <textarea required name="descr" id="descr" rows="10" cols="10"></textarea>

                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Upload an image <span class="required">*</span>
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                      <img id="image-preview" alt="image preview" />
                      <br />
                      <input type="file" name="image-source" id="image-source" onchange="previewImage();" required />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

## DASHBOARD VIEW

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
          <?php 
            if($announcements = $this->Bid_Model->fetchItems('announcements')):
            foreach ($announcements as $announce): 
              if($announce->user_type == 6){?>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2>Announcement</h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="<?=base_url()?>Admin/deleteAnnouncement/<?=$announce->announcement_id?>" class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="x_content">
                <center>
                  <img src="<?php echo base_url().'uploads/';?>announcements/<?=$announce->image;?>" height="500" width="700">

                  <h4><?=$announce->title?></h4>
                  <h4><?=$announce->content?></h4>
                </center>

                <div class="ln_solid"></div>
                  <!-- modals -->

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
             <?php } endforeach; endif; ?>
                  <!-- /modals -->
          <br />
```

## MODEL

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Bid_Model extends CI_Model {

    function fetchItems($table, $data = NULL){
        if ($data != NULL){
            $this->db->where($data);
        }

        $query = $this->db->get($table);
        return ($query->num_rows() > 0) ? $query->result() : FALSE;
    }

    function deleteItem($table,$array=NULL){
        if($array!=NULL){
            $this->db->where($array);
             $this->db->delete($table);
        }else{
            $this->db->empty_table($table); 
        } 
    }

    function insertItem($table, $data = NULL){
        $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    }

    function insertItems($table,$data = array()){
        $this->db->insert_batch($table, $data);
    }


    function updateItem($table, $data, $var = NULL){
        if($var != NULL){
            $this->db->where($var);
        }
        $this->db->update($table, $data);
    }


}
```

Comment: see this link [https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#inserting-data]

Comment: change the name of text  field into array then only the multiple rows saved in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've said you want to insert multiple rows, I assume that you want to do a batch-insert using data previously selected from `fetchItems()` function. You could try it like this :

```
        $newData = $this->Bid_Model->fetchItems('accounts');

        if($users == $uType){

            $announce_image = $this->upload->data('file_name');
            $data = []; // new empty array
            foreach($newData as $user):
                $userIDs = $user->user_id;

                $data[] = array(
                    'title' => $title,
                    'user_type' => $users,
                    'content' => $content,
                    'image' => $announce_image,
                    'admin_user_id' => $id,
                    'user_id' => $userIDs
                ); 
            endforeach;

            $this->Bid_Model->insertItems('announcements', $data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that data passed to `insertItems` is all cleaned and you want to insert it directly to DB without any changes.

DB function:

```
function insert_batch($data) {
   $query = 'INSERT INTO TABLE (`title`, `user_type`, `content`, `image`, 
                                `admin_user_id`, `user_id`) VALUES ';
   $insert_data = [];
   for($x=0; $x<count($data); $x++){
    $insert_data[] = "('" . $data['title'] . "', '" . $data['user_type'] . "', '" . $data['content'] . "', '" . $data['image'] . "', '" . $data['admin_user_id'] . "','" . $column2['user_id'] . "')";
    }
    $query .= implode(',', $insert_data); //Execute this $query
}
```